# Meta Refresh: Count starts after page load or before?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html">
```

Does the count start from full page load or as soon as the page is loading.

Having tested it, it looks to me it starts counting after full page load?

I appreciate a confirm before I continue with this solution. I didn't like Javascripts timeout.

Will this play nicely with IE6?

Comment: Interesting question... however, keep in mind that meta refresh has been deprecated by W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element

Comment: @Daniel: *Very* interesting, more details here (linked from your page): http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh

Comment: @Daniel: As there's no mention of deprecation in the HTML5 spec (http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/meta.http-equiv.refresh.html), I'm not sure that's applicable anymore -- not least because it's not from the core spec, it's part of accessibility "guidelines" from nine years ago that say (amongst other things) that they are "...[not] the only way an author might produce conforming content."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect it's implementation-dependent when this happens (although that doesn't mean all implementations don't do much the same thing; one would have to test). The [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/meta.http-equiv.refresh.html) doesn't address when the countdown begins.

But how much does it really matter? The time is in seconds, and we're all shooting for sub-second page load times anyway, right? ;-)

IE6 respects the `refresh` header, yes (including as a `meta` tag).

Comment: More importantly - we're all shooting for post-1990s, non-deprecated techniques, so are using one of the many proper alternatives instead of meta-refresh tags, right? ;-)

Comment: @Andrzej: :-) I didn't realize (tsk!) it was deprecated until Daniel's comment above; and I find it odd that they don't mention that in the HTML5 spec, I wonder if that deprecation is outdated. I'm not seeing a non-JavaScript alternative for certain use cases; in the absense of one, it seems inappropriate to deprecate an existing mechanism. They may have gotten feedback on that.

Comment: @TJ Crowder: It looks like W3C may have deprecated the deprecation for meta-refresh in HTML5 :)

Comment: it matters to some, if the page was supposed to fully load an iframe before redirecting

Answer (score 1):

I think after page load too, and Yes, its working well with IE6.

but best way is the redirecting with [301, 302 URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/301_redirect#HTTP_status_codes_3xx) from server, Meta Refresh is kind of deprecated one, still working though.

Comment: `refresh` has a different purpose than a 301 or 302; it allows presenting a page and then refreshing it (or replacing it) *after an interval*. (But good to point the author at 301 and 302 in case they're more appropriate for what he's doign.)